# Failure Authenticating with Service Fabric Primary Certificate

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a cluster that I've been using without issue for a few months.  It has 2 certificates created about the same time - so nowhere near expired.  Last week, builds stopped working due to a certificate error (CertificateNotMatched) on deployment.  At the same time, I was unable to access or publish with Visual Studio.  I checked the cert and it appears to not be revoked or invalid in any way.  The secondary certificate is still working fine.

What could cause a certificate to stop working spontaneously?  Is there any fix apart from just getting a new certificate when this occurs?

Comment: can you connect from PowerShell using the same thumbprint (Connect-ServiceFabric)?

Comment: No, this fails as well unless I use the secondary, which works fine.

Comment: Is said certificate still valid if you go to Azure Management Portal?

Comment: Where in the portal can you check certificate validity?